# laravel 4 one to many relationships - iteration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to improve some code in my app in laravel 4 and trying to implement relationships between models.

I have a table called reservations which has a one to many relationship with items. Items has a one to one relationship with Products. Basically as a reservation the items that are included in the reservation are added to the items table. The specs of the items comes from the products table (type, value etc)

I've set up the relationships in the models as follows:

in the reservations Class:

```
public function item() {
        return $this->hasMany('Item');
    }
```

in the items Class:

```
public function reservation() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Reservation');
    }
public function product() {
        return $this->hasOne('Product');
    }
```

in the product Class:

```
public function item() {
        return $this->belongsTo('item');
    }
```

I'm trying to now query the reservations for a calendar view. I'm retrieving all the reservations in a month using the following:

```
$events = Reservation::where('play_date','>=',$start->format('Y-m-d'))
            ->where('play_date','<=', $end->format('Y-m-d'))
            ->get();
```

I'm then trying to iterate through the collection (is it a collection or a result set?) using the following:

```
$events->each(function($event) { }
```

I then want to iterate through all the items of the reservation and it's this bit that's confusing me.

```
$items = $event->item()->get();
```

which does create an object I can then iterate through this sub collection using another call back but I'm then struggling to get the product information using:

```
$item->product()->type
```

I get an error:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne::$type
```

How can I iterate through the items correctly using laravel relationships? What is the best practice in this and retrieve details relating to the item from the product table

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure, but it looks like what you're trying to do here is a Many-to-Many relationship, between Reservations and Products.

Comment: This may be the case. I'm not 100%. Basically the items table stores details of the items included for each reservation plus some related fields such as session start and end for the product - I'm learning as I go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main point to do what you want is understand the difference between `$event->item` and `$event->item()`. Basically, `$event->item` is the same as `$event->item()->get()`. Knowing this, you should be doing something like this

```
$events = Reservation::where('play_date', '>=', $start->format('Y-m-d'))
                     ->where('play_date', '<=', $end->format('Y-m-d'))
                     ->get();

$events->each(function ($event) {
    $items = $event->item;
    $items->each(function ($item) {
        $type = $item->product->type;
    });
});
```

You may also want to take a look at [Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading) your relationships, as to reduce the number of queries ran.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still learning the relationship side of L4. I tried implementing your code and I get an error `Unknown column 'products.item_id' in 'where clause'` it seems to be doing the reverse of what I expect - I changed the item<->product relationship to item belongsTo product and product hasMany items and it works so looks like it should be many to many relationship?

Comment: Not necessarily. The main point to consider is if `items` table is only a way to link `products` with `reservations`. If so, it should be a Many-to-Many relationship.